# Is there a word for "shadow"?

Tags: translation

"Shadow" meaning "a person who accompanies someone in their daily activities at work in order to gain experience at or insight into a job."

Comment: “村里来的新人”，a funny way to say that.

Answer (score 7):

The term " to shadow "(跟随/跟著) means 'follow (closely like a shadow)'.

Example:

> "Today is your first day on the job, you don't have to do anything, just **shadowing** John and watch how he works."
>
> (今天是你工作的第一天，你不用做任何事情，只要**跟著**約翰, 看看他是如何工作便可以了.)

For a noun that describes 'someone who does the shadowing'

I suggest '**見習生**'

Example:

> "you would be John's **shadow** today"
>
> (你今天就當約翰的**見習生**吧)

~

> 見習 (v) to watch and learn
>
> 見習生(n) a person on job probation (watch and learn)

*見習生 is a general term, It can be a student training in actual work place or a new employee starting a job on probation. Different companies have different training methods. Shadowing is one kind of 見習, which trainee can learn by observing, and not hamper the trainer's regular work routine.*

Comment: 見習生 is probably the closest one here. Keeping my options open. :)

Comment: 見習生 is used in the hospital for clerks (clerkship), they shadow physicians/other medical professions

Comment: @辛祐賦hsinyofu Did you mean that 見習生 could only refer to medical practitioners early in their career?

Answer (score 1):

Is 学徒(apprentice) what you are looking for?

Comment: 学徒 is a noun. OP is looking for a verb for 'to shadow' , which means  'follow someone closely like a shadow'

Comment: 学徒 doesn't quite hit the mark.

Comment: @TangHo Actually "a person who..." describes a noun.

Answer (score 1):

A few verbs that can be used with the “師傅” “徒弟” relationship :

```
跟班
隨從
跟從
侍從
```

Comment: These look more like "footman" or "servant" to me.

Comment: 盯梢 is similar to shadow in the sense that it also signifies following someone secretly, otherwise the only one I have is 陪伴 which you can use with a trainer i.e. 教練陪伴著實習生, I don't know if you can get closer than that with a direct translation

Answer (score 0):

你跟着她做。 Follow her, watch what she does.